# Cross-border account access for EU states

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, banking

If an individual in, for example, Lithuania sells his home and disagrees with the state on taxation and then the state goes after the taxes through Lithuanian courts.
As the individual has no assets in Lithuania but a bank account in the UK, can the Lithuanian state freeze or recover funds from an UK account?

UK is not a member of EAPO (European Account Preservation Order) but it's said their banks would co-operate with EU claims.

We're talking relatively small amounts of money (less than $30k EUR) and not criminal proceeds.
Comments such as "it's always better to pay your taxes" are deemed unhelpful.

Comment: `Lithuanian state freeze or recover funds from an UK account` Yes they can. But will they do it or not, no one knows.  `it's always better to pay your taxes` So why wouldn't you pay your taxes ? This website doesn't help people in defrauding anybody else. If you want to dispute go ahead and get a lawyer rather than trying to find loopholes to stop paying your taxes.

Comment: Of course people know because it does happen. A case can be won in court but meanwhile funds can be frozen, so stop assuming tax departments are always in the right because they aren't. It's a valid question based on international laws and current practices.

Comment: Also, for most countries this is not the standard practice. Tax issues such as this are not international standards, for example Japan won't care that Nepal didn't get it's lawful taxes and they won't assist Nepal in seeking these taxes. So I'm more curious about EU with UK's special status.

Comment: You seem to be taking a too cavalier attitude regarding taxation. If you are so sure that the tax amount is wrong why not get in touch with the authorities and ask them how to get it rectified rather than going online and trying shortcuts.

Comment: My attitude is irrelevant and you're not being objective. What I'm describing is common and happens every day around the world. You might attempt to read a case or two.

Comment: This seems more about law than personal finance. A question about whether the state's calculations are right or not probably should be here; a question about whether a state can freeze overseas accounts probably should be on Law.SE.

Answer (score 2):

> As the individual has no assets in Lithuania but a bank account in the UK, can the Lithuanian state freeze or recover funds from an UK account?

Yes they can. There are various [tax recovery agreement within EU](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/business/tax-cooperation-control/tax-recovery_en) as well as Internationally. So the tax authorities can use these means to freeze or recover funds from UK accounts. For Lithuania tax authorities, It is more easy in EU to recover taxes compared to other geographies.

As to whether the Lithuania tax authorities will pursue it for the said amount can't be predicted.